# Write a Linked List‐based variant of Q2. Following will be the function prototype:

Tags: c

int find(struct node *list, int x, int start);
The return value of this recursive function should be the index (position) of x, if x
is indeed present in the list. If x is not in the list, it will return ‐1. e.g. if x is the
data of the first node, the function should return 0, and so on.

Comment: What exactly is the question?

Comment: that is definitely homework..if you show us what have you done till now and what is the *exact* problem you are facing somebody will help..nobody is going to write the full code for you..

Comment: Yes, homework. And I would guess that this assignment starts with Qx where x > 2.

Answer (score 1):

You have two possibilities.
Either you can iterate through the list (with "while") looking for the necessary element and return the found value afterwards, or you can recursively call the same function on the list which contains one element less each step and then look only for the first element of the list. In this case you should call this function unless you have no more elements or you have the necessary element found.
If you provide the code you have created, the society definitely will help you to fix it.